# how to create Sortable datatable in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, sorting, datatable

I found package "Editable", but I'm unable to make datatable sortable.
How can I do this?

I created a table with three columns. Given that the table size grows, I started finding a way to make it sortable to facilitate usage

Comment: Have you tried the built in [Datatable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable-class.html) or [PaginatedDataTable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PaginatedDataTable-class.html) ? If you have, show the code you have that isn't working.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I succeeded using the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wYM1w8emtN8&pp=ygUbIGZsdXR0ZXIgUGFnaW5hdGVkRGF0YVRhYmxl

Comment: Thanks @Wh1t3rabbit for your help, I succeeded using the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wYM1w8emtN8&pp=ygUbIGZsdXR0ZXIgUGFnaW5hdGVkRGF0YVRhYmxl